# How to change firefox tab context menu to chrome way?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, context-menu

`tab context menu` is refered to this

[image]

The feature I usually used in chrome is

1. right click tabs, open context menu
2. context menu first menu item is "open new tab", click it open a new tab

But I don't see this in Firefox 57 .

Comment: You are supposed to click the '+' tab to open a new one.

Comment: Alternatively use Ctrl+T.

Comment: @harrymc I need move cursor to `+` , so prefer right click   @Seth It is a habbit to use mouse to open new tab,  as I like to use `ctrl + w` close tab.

Answer (score 0):

There are add-ons that add to the Firefox tab menu the "New tab" option,
but all of them are marked in the Store as "Not compatible with Firefox Quantum". For example
the add-on of [New Tab in Tab Context Menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-in-tab-context-menu/).

However, Firefox Quantum version 57 has seriously crippled the ability of
add-ons to intervene in the functioning of the browser engine itself,
so they are currently limited to only modifying the displayed contents.

You might opt for using instead a Firefox fork that still allows add-ons
to modify the behavior of the engine, such as
[Waterfox](https://superuser.com/questions/1268359/how-to-prevent-automatic-update-to-firefox-57-0-quantum).

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1271866/8672)
and its comments for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Duplicate tab` item from the same context menu and then use it as a new tab.