# Install Firefox without updates

Tags: firefox, updates

I would like to install an older version of Firefox. I have seen some similar
questions but this is different as I need to disable the initial update not
future updates. I visited this page:

https://support.mozilla.org/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

which points me here:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/65.0.2/win32/en-US/

However it seems any method I use results in an upgraded version. I have tried
this method:

1. install Firefox 65.0.2
2. launch Firefox
3. disable updates
4. restart Firefox

and this:

1. install Firefox 65.0.2
2. launch Firefox
3. disable updates
4. exit Firefox
5. install Firefox again
6. launch Firefox again
7. restart Firefox

but in both cases Firefox gets updated to version 66.0.3. How can I install an
older Firefox without it updating?

Comment: More of a `softwarerecs.stackexchange.com` so posting as comment instead of answer... but how about the ESR release? Current version is v60 ... https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/

Comment: Once you've disabled updates in a profile it should stay disabled. Just don't start your older version of Firefox with a profile that doesn't have updates disabled. You can have more than one version of Firefox installed at a time on your machine (I have several) by selecting to install it to a different directory or folder. You can then use the current version for the first operation of any particular profile. However, I've normally had no problem using a fresh profile on an older FF version and not having FF update. I just have to remember to disable updates as the first thing I do.

Comment: @Three I currently have an older version of Firefox running and many older versions installed. When FF66 was available, I recall that Firefox asked if it could update to FF66. I routinely use more than one installation of the current version, in addition to several older versions. Firefox had no problem with 65.0.2 being installed and running while FF66 was also installed. It did not force the update to FF66. If you've actually disabled updates, or at least selected "Check for updates but let you choose to install them", then Firefox will not automatically update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent automatic update to Firefox 57.0 Quantum?](https://superuser.com/questions/1268359/how-to-prevent-automatic-update-to-firefox-57-0-quantum)

Comment: Also duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1325421/how-do-i-stop-firefox-from-notifying-me-about-updates

Comment: Your method 2 usually works for me, though sometimes it takes a second round of re-installation.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a workaround:

1. when installing, uncheck "Launch Firefox now"
2. delete

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\updater.exe
   ```

Note that you will still see the message "Restart to update Firefox", but if you
restart the old version will remain. An alternative workaround is:

1. when installing, uncheck "Launch Firefox now"
2. navigate to

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\channel-prefs.js
   ```
3. add this line

   ```js
   pref('app.update.auto', false);
   ```

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336267

Answer (score 2):

You can use the appropriate version of Firefox Portable:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disconnecting your computer from the internet on first launch?

That should prevent the auto-update from being able to run, and let you change settings without it being able to download any updates first.

Comment: Ive used this exact tactic to accomplish this task.